# intellij community edition doesn't hot reload CSS files

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij IDEA community edition 2017.2, apparently the community edition is not compatible with the live reload plugin. However, when I update a HTML file it will get automatically reloaded. I don't understand why CSS files in the same project don't automatically reload as well.

How do I get my css files to hot reload?

Comment: Please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26730 for updates.